# What would you call bitcoin wallet that give access to private keys unlike coinbase.com for example?

Tags: e-wallet

Any Suggestions?

I suggest Non-custodial Bitcoin Wallet, But i feel it's not appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Bitcoin Wallet is what I would call it. A wallet on a central service with no access to the private keys I would call a “custodial” wallet.